# display iReport with photo from java code

Tags: java

I want ro display a report from java which contains a photo blob from data base, but it return me this exception

> Byte data not found at location : java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@6b9ea0a7

but if I remove the photo the report shown up normally or if I change the property of the image "On error to blank"
this is the java code

```
public void genere(){
    try{
        String xmlFile = "D:\\1-LICENCE\\Logiciel\\MAGAZINE\\magazine\\mag.jrxml";
        String jasperFile = "D:\\1-LICENCE\\Logiciel\\MAGAZINE\\magazine\\magazine.jasper";
        String pdfFile = "D:\\1-LICENCE\\Logiciel\\MAGAZINE\\magazine\\magazine.pdf";

        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader
                .load(xmlFile);
        String sql = "SELECT "
                + "article.n_article AS article_n_article,article.titre AS article_titre,"
                + "article.article AS article_article,article.image AS article_image,"
                + "article.code_domaine_domaine AS article_code_domaine_domaine,"
                + "article.num_mag_magazine AS article_num_mag_magazine,"
                + "article.matricule_auteur AS article_matricule_auteur,"
                + "auteur.matricule AS auteur_matricule,auteur.nom AS auteur_nom,"
                + "domaine.code_domaine AS domaine_code_domaine,domaine.nom_domaine AS domaine_nom_domaine,"
                + "magazine.num_mag AS magazine_num_mag,magazine.date_mag AS magazine_date_mag"
                + " FROM article "
                + "INNER JOIN auteur ON article.matricule_auteur=auteur.matricule "
                + "INNER JOIN domaine ON article.code_domaine_domaine=domaine.code_domaine "
                + "INNER JOIN magazine ON article.num_mag_magazine=magazine.num_mag WHERE num_mag_magazine='"
                + cmbMag.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);
        jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, cnx);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(print,false);

        //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, pdfFile);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Logger.getLogger(Generator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: [This](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534101/image-resource-not-found) might be of interest to you.

Comment: thank you but it's not the same problem, my image is saved on the data base as blob, that's what cause the problem